# PowerBI Gantt Chart Will Only Accept Limit on One End and Not the Other

Tags: date, powerbi, calendar, calculation, gantt-chart

In a PowerBi Gantt chart, I had added two formulas to calculate the previous month from this month and a different formula to calculate the next month from this month.

The relevant fields contain this figures:

Start: Date Completion (Date) / Prev Month (Measure)
End: Date Completion (Date) / Next Month (Figure)

The goal was for the Gantt chart to show the following months: November December January

When using both formulas, the result says there is no data.

Result when using just the Prev Month measure: December 2023 to May 2024
Result when using just the Next Month measure: March 2022 to January 2024

[The previous month description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kVBlv.png)
[When entering both month calculations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EA2Et.png)

Here is a link to the file. The goal is to show the previous month, the current month, and the next month. The most I have been able to get is this month and the next month.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1GKj_f18zeOQtEIroiIP-kgFmtQXXPDkN/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Could you upload/share a sample PBIX and post a link to it in your question? (via for example OneDrive, GoogleDrive, DropBox etc...)

Comment: Updated the original post with the link.

Comment: I'm unclear what you mean by "Start: Date Completion (Date) / Prev Month (Measure) End: Date Completion (Date) / Next Month", are you wanting to show only tasks that are in the 3 month window?

Comment: Yes, I am only looking to keep it within a three-month window: the last month, the current month, and the next month. If I were to look at it now, it would be November, December, January.

Comment: If task A starts in May and ends in Dec, show or hide? If task B starts in Dec and ends in Feb, show or hide?

Comment: Show for both if the end date fits with the previous month/current month/next month time period.

Comment: To be clear, Task B therefore won't be shown since its end date is beyond the next month, regardless of it starting in this month?

Comment: Correct. The only tasks to populate would be those that are due.